# Map not shown after obtaining a release key

Tags: android, debugging, release, android-mapview

As long as I had a debug key, I could see the map (mapview). Today I have obtained a release key at Goolge's site (after generating a certificate fingetprint). Once I replaced the debug key with the new release key I have obtained, the map is not shown anymore. Is there additional step I have to take before I can see the maps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How you test it? With release key you not gonna see the map in debug or run options, only in exported and signed app, with the same key what you used to retrive the map key.

If you want to see the map keep using the debug key and switch to the release one only then when you really export you application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these tutorials (from 28th to 31)Thought might be useful.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgr4l1nsFdU

It explains Google Maps set up in a very detailed step by step manner.